# other way to update eclipse android plugin

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

i am having problem where i cannot download the plugin from the eclipse.

i already tried using `http` and `https` but it shows the error below. is there a way for me to update the plugin?

im using eclipse helios and it is version 3.6.

i had recently update my sdk and it says it need to update the ADT but i tried it over and over again still it would show the same error.

please.

[image]

Comment: I sometimes could resolve such problems by installing from a clean workspace.

Answer (score 0):

try download the ADT plugin as a zip file from this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) and then install it from archive.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in the [Troubleshooting](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html#Troubleshooting) section of the ADT installation. They explain very detailed how to install the ADT offline from the downloaded archive.